# JPA OneToMany - Collection is null

Tags: java, jpa, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to set up a bidirectional relationship using JPA. I understand that it's the responsability of the application to maintain both sides of the relationship.

For example, a Library has multiple Books. In the Library-entity I have:

```
@Entity
public class Library {
  ..
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "library", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Collection<Book> books;

  public void addBook(Book b) {
    this.books.add(b);
    if(b.getLibrary() != this)
      b.setLibrary(this);
  }
  ..
}
```

The Book-entity is:

```
@Entity
public class Book {
  ..
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "LibraryId")
  private Library library;

  public void setLibrary(Library l) {
    this.library = l;
    if(!this.library.getBooks().contains(this))
      this.library.getBooks().add(this);
  }
  ..
}
```

Unfortunately, the collection at the OneToMany-side is null. So for example a call to setLibrary() fails because this.library.getBooks().contains(this) results in a NullPointerException.

Is this normal behavior? Should I instantiate the collection myself (which seems a bit strange), or are there other solutions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Entities are Java objects. The basic rules of Java aren't changed just because there is an `@Entity` annotation on the class.

So, if you instantiate an object and its constructor doesn't initialize one of the fields, this field is initialized to null.

Yes, it's your responsibility to make sure that the constructor initializes the collection, or that all the methods deal with the nullability of the field.

If you get an instance of this entity from the database (using em.find(), a query, or by navigating through associations of attached entities), the collection will never be null, because JPA will always initialize the collection.

Comment: Just a note that the last part of that isn't completely true.  If you call the getter outside of the transaction, JPA will have reset your collection to null, even if you initialized it in the constructor.  If you have long-running processes and don't want to leave the transaction open, make sure to explicitly call the getter before you leave the transaction.

Comment: No, that's incorrect. The collection will be an uninitialized proxy in that case, and thus calling any method on it will fail, but it won't be null.

Comment: Uninitialized or null - I get a NullpointerException. @JBNizet you write, that  " it's your responsibility to make sure that the constructor initializes the collection" and then you say "JPA will always initialize the collection".

Comment: @theFriedC Ask your own question, with your own code, and the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: There is no need for a new question. In my case I switched to eager loading, since the collection is from type @ElementCollection with just a few entries.

Comment: So, you downvoted (I guess) my correct answer because it correctly answered a problem that wasn't the same as yours?

Comment: YES I downvoted. NO the problem was the same as mine. Don't you think you contradict yourself with the two statements I quoted? What do you think about the answer of @MouseLearnJava? ... PS: I tried to undo my downvote already, but stackoverflow won't let me

Comment: No, I don't. If you just execute `Library lib = new Library()`, JPA is not involved at all. You have a class, and you create an instance. That initializes the fields according to the instructions contained in the constructor that you wrote. On the other hand, when you do `Library lib = em.find(Library.class, 42L)`, then JPA is involved. It finds the row in the database, calls the no-arg constructor of Library, then uses reflection to populate all its non-transient fields with the data it fetches from the database.

Comment: If the collection of books is lazy, it doesn't know what to put in the collection, but it still lnows that a library has a collection of 0-N books, so it initializes the books field with an uninitialized collection proxy. The first time any method is called on the collection, that will load the books from the DB and fill the collection, or throw a LazyInitializationException if the entity is detached.

Comment: Actually, my statement is correct, as noted by others as well.  A NullPointerException occurs when it is set to null.  As you've said, the basic rules of Java aren't changed.

Answer (score 8):

It seems that books type of  Collection in Library class is not initilized. It is null;

So when class addBook method to add a book object to collection. It cause NullPointerException.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "library", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 private Collection<Book> books;

 public void addBook(Book b) {
    this.books.add(b);
    if(b.getLibrary() != this)
    b.setLibrary(this);
 }
```

Initilize it and have a try.

Change

```
private Collection<Book> books;
```

To

```
private Collection<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the fetch type association property to eager on the OneToMany side. Indeed, you may leave this part (this.library.getBooks().add(this)) to be written within a session:

```
Library l = new Library();    
Book b = new Book();
b.setLibrary(l);
l.getBooks().add(b);
```