# What is point of OneToMany and ManyToOne anotations, if I have to fill List<Object> manually?

Tags: jpa

I am desperate to make my project work, basically what I have is a Company and Product tables in database. I wanted to make unidirectional relation between those two, but there is no way I could fill List of products in Company object. What I found on StackOverflow, is this answer

> Entities are Java objects. The basic rules of Java aren't changed just
>   because there is an @Entity annotation on the class.
>
> So, if you instantiate an object and its constructor doesn't
>   initialize one of the fields, this field is initialized to null.
>
> Yes, it's your responsibility to make sure that the constructor
>   initializes the collection, or that all the methods deal with the
>   nullability of the field.

Original can be found here.
 [JPA OneToMany - Collection is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030771/jpa-onetomany-collection-is-null)

So I am asking, what is the point of having those Anotations if I have to fill the list in constructor?

EDIT:

Some code just for example...
Company object

```
     @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "company", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
     private transient List<Product> productList;
```

And the Product object

```
    @ManyToOne(optional = false,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Company company; //however, in database I have field of type int as a foreign key, I dont need company object here...
```

EDIT 2:
I know that by using 
`new Company();` it won't fill ProductList but the way I am getting the company is

```
em.createNamedQuery("Company.findById", Company.class).setParameter("id", id).getResultList();
```

FINAL EDIT:
removing transient keyword did the trick.

I'm sorry I didn't think of that "transient"could cause problems. That was my mistake because of laziness. I used transient because it was causing some trouble when serializing with GSON and there were two options of making it work, one is using Expose annotation and the other one was transient, and it looked like a good idea. I was trying to make it work too hard and didn't realize where is the real problem, so once again sorry, this question is pointless. I thought even with OneToMany annotation it does not fill my List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that JPA will instantiate and fill them for you when loading objects from the database. But not when you create instances from thin air.

`new Company()` creates a new Company instance, and JPA doesn't know anything about it. So yes, obviously, in that case, the company's product is null, since the constructor doesn't set it to anything else.

On the other hand, `em.find(Company.class, 23L)` will return the Company from the database which has the ID 23, and this company will have a non-null list of products, containing the products of the company.

Comment: Yes I know but funny thing is, the way I am getting the company is not "new Company()" but         
List<Company> lc = em.createNamedQuery("Company.findById", Company.class).setParameter("id", id).getResultList();

        if(!lc.isEmpty())
            return lc.get(0);

And it gives me the company but does not fill ProductList

Comment: Remove `transient` from the list declaration. Also, if that is the problem you're facing, why are you doing a completely different question?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't think of that "Transient"could cause problems. That was my mistake because of laziness. I used transient because it was causing some trouble when serializing with GSON and there were two options of making it work, one is using Expose annotation and the other one was transient, and it looked like a good idea. I was trying to make it work too hard so once again sorry, this question is pointless. I thought even with OneToMany annotation it does not fill my List