# Return an empty list on @OneToMany that is indeed 0 to many (nullable)

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa, join

I have a FK that recursively points to the very same entity, but it can't be nullable

*Person* entity:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "personId", referencedColumnName = "managerId", updatable = false, insertable = false, nullable = true)
private List<Person> managers;
```

But this is returning null instead of an empty list when the join is null. The problem is that I am not sure it's an error, or a design fault. While debugging, child person shows managers as a persistent bag, but orphan persons have no empty persistent bag but a null value.

But in this question, a user affirms the list should always be initialized: [To initialize or not initialize JPA relationship mappings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715143/to-initialize-or-not-initialize-jpa-relationship-mappings)

Just for your info, theres no LazyLoadingExceptions as all the code is within a @Transactional

In this other question ([JPA OneToMany - Collection is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030771/jpa-onetomany-collection-is-null)) there's an explanation about JPA using noargs constructor and setting fields directly from db, so I am wondering if the problem is that JPA sets the list to null because the fb returns the join column as null. If that were the case, would it be a way to tell JPA to send an empty list instead of null?

The code for fetching is a test:

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void fetchManagersOfCEO(){
    Person person = this.personRepository.findOne(1L);
    assertThat(result.getManagers().size()).isEqualTo(0);
}
```

This return expected managers when the id is the one of an employee with managers above

P.S> After a lot of debugging, the problem is that JPA is setting the collection to null, no "COLLECTION NOT NULL" ObjectMarker, and empty CollectionReferenceInitializers

I don't like it but the only way I found to work out the issue is:

```
public List<Person> getManagers(){
    return Optional.ofNullable(this.managers).orElseGet(ArrayList::new);
}
```

Comment: please add hibernate code where are you fetching list

Comment: I just did it, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Just do this:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "personId", referencedColumnName = "managerId", updatable = false, insertable = false, nullable = true)
private List<Person> managers = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Sorry, it did not worked. I forgot to mention. I think Hibernate takes null from the join column and setts it manually overriding the initialized Arraylist. And I cannot do it final for other reasons

Comment: There is no need to make it final. A bit of a shot in the dark, but might be something with updatable etc, do you really need those? Nullable = true makes no sense at least.. Could you try to remove these?

Comment: In the javadoc it says nullable refers to the join column and the join column is manager_position which can be null

Comment: (and it's supposedly only for DDL anyway)

Comment: OK, I don't see why Hibernate would set anything to null. This works in my projects, but then again I don't have many self-referencing relationships, so might be something there.

Comment: But there is something I don't get with your modelling here. With a OneToMany, then a manager can only manage one person. Also, the referencedColumnName is strange, why is not the id of the person? How is this column populated?

Comment: oops.. you are right, in my simplification I made it illogical. Imagine that personId is not the PK and that several registers for the same person can exist

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have entity A that has one to many entity B.

You can then replicate your problem by:

- Creating A with no (null) list of B.
- Persisting A.
- Fetching A **in the same transaction**.

This is because Hibernate refers to the same object in a single transaction and the object has null as a list of B.

However, if you are in two separate transactions or if you manually clear the session (*SessionFactory.clear* or *EntityManager.clear*) then the list should properly be initialized with an empty persistent bag.